# PySpark - Convert key value data into row column data

Tags: python, pandas, pyspark

Running into a problem with efficiently converting key value data to column data.

I have a table with the structure of

| accountkey | accountfield | accountvalue |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 101 | field1 | value1 |
| 101 | field2 | value2 |
| 102 | field1 | value3 |
| 102 | field2 | value4 |

and I am looking to convert this into something with the below structure:

| accountkey | field1 | field2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 101 | value1 | value2 |
| 102 | value3 | value4 |

I should note that this table is also significantly large than the above example so wouldn't be able to do this by hand. Trying to do this with dictionaries appears to be very slow (and has crashed a few times) and am unsure of how to use any map/reduce functionality.

I specifically tried

```
rdd = table.rdd
key_value_rdd = rdd.map(lambda row : (row['accountfield'], row['accountvalue']) )
```

but this looks to only be creating one key value pair for the whole table.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `pivot`:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as f

df = (
    df
    .groupBy('accountkey')
    .pivot('accountfield')
    .agg(f.first('accountvalue'))
)
```